# BigQuery gives inconsistent results

Tags: google-bigquery

Do anyone know why BigQuery can give inconsistent results. I run three different queries, they should all give the same result, but they all differ.

For each user session I store the device type (iOS only so this is either ipad or iphone) and a bool that says if a user has notifcations on or off. I've checked that these values are never NULL and the device_type is nothing other than 'ipad' or 'iphone'.

But when I run the following query:

```
select (SELECT count(distinct user_id) FROM `session` where notifications = True) + (SELECT count(distinct user_id) FROM `session` where notifications = False)
```

I get **9615** as the sum. When I run:

```
select (SELECT count(distinct user_id) FROM `session` where device_type = 'ipad') + (SELECT count(distinct user_id) FROM `session` where device_type = 'iphone')
```

The sum is **9588**. And when I run:

```
select count(distinct user_id) FROM `session`
```

It gives me **9585**. So **9615**, **9588** and **9585** although they should all be the same. And I've ran them in multiple orders and tried filtering out any entires set within the last day.

What can cause this? I don't see any logical errors, is this just some BigQuery behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery uses approximate aggregations to perform better with big datasets. You can use exact aggregation if approximation is not appropriate in your case. The default behaviour depends on the SQL dialect you use: Legacy SQL defaults to approximate and Standard SQL defaults to exact.

I assume you are using legacy sql and you can use `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT` function to get exact counts. More info on legacy sql count distinct  functions can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#countdistinct.

You can find more information from this document https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate-aggregation.

Comment: Oh, that's it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Although, maybe I spoke too soon. I am using standard sql, and there's a 'APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT' that should be used if you're looking for approximate numbers (which would in practice be the case for us). So count(distinct X) should according to the documentation give exact results, if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: With standard sql it should be exact distinct count by default. Have you double checked your data so that you do not have multiple sessions for same user_id with different values for notifications or device_types fields? This would cause that same user_id is counted multiple times.

Comment: hey, yeah so that was exactly it. I started digging deeper into the rows that made the numbers miss-match and you're completely right, some had notifications turned on at first and later off, so some user_ids were counted multiple times. Thanks alot for this! Also,good to learn about APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT as that's often enough! And seeing you're from Finland as well, I'll buy you a beer if we even meet-up!

Answer (score 0):

Hope below simplified example show exactly why this happens - mostly because of distinct

```
#standardSQL
WITH `session` AS (
  SELECT 1 user_id, TRUE notifications, 'ipad' device_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 user_id, TRUE notifications, 'iphone' device_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 user_id, TRUE notifications, 'ipad' device_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 user_id, FALSE notifications, 'iphone' device_type 
)
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM `session` WHERE notifications = TRUE) + 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM `session` WHERE notifications = FALSE) AS query1,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM `session` WHERE device_type = 'ipad') + 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM `session` WHERE device_type = 'iphone') AS query2,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM `session`) AS query3
```

with output

```
Row query1  query2  query3   
1   3       4       2
```

While below (distinct-less) version

```
#standardSQL
WITH `session` AS (
  SELECT 1 user_id, TRUE notifications, 'ipad' device_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 user_id, TRUE notifications, 'iphone' device_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 user_id, TRUE notifications, 'ipad' device_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 user_id, FALSE notifications, 'iphone' device_type 
)
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `session` WHERE notifications = TRUE) + 
  (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `session` WHERE notifications = FALSE) AS query1,
  (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `session` WHERE device_type = 'ipad') + 
  (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `session` WHERE device_type = 'iphone') AS query2,
  (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `session`) AS query3
```

results with

```
Row query1  query2  query3   
1   4       4       4
```